# Does Azure Event Hub Limit the Number of Topics?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to use Azure Event Hubs as a message bus using the Confluent Kafka sdk's.  When I started testing my code, it was working, but after I created 10 topics, I can no longer create any new topics.  I am using IAdminClient.CreateTopicsAsync to create the topics.  I can use MetaData.Topics.ToList() to see that the first 10 topics that I created are still there, I just can't create any new ones.  I used IAdminClient.DeleteTopicsAsyn to delete one of my topics, and after that I was able to add 1 new one, bringing the total back up to 10.  I still cannot create an 11th.  Is there some kind of limit that would allow me to create 10 topics, but not an 11th?  Is this something I can increase with a simple configuration change?  Thank you.

Error thrown by CreateTopicsAsync:

> CreateTopicsException: An error occurred creating topics:
> [TopicName11]: [The service was unable to process the request; please
> retry the operation. For more information on exception types and
> proper exception handling, please refer to
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101].

Comment: If you wouldn't mind sharing how you got `CreateTopicAsync` to work, that would be very much appreciated, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212255/how-can-i-create-a-topic-on-event-hub-kafka-using-the-adminclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; a topic in Kafka is synonymous with an Event Hub in the Event Hubs ecosystem.  *(see: [Kafka and Event Hub conceptual mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-for-kafka-ecosystem-overview#kafka-and-event-hub-conceptual-mapping))*.

Each Event Hubs namespace has a limit on the number of Event Hub instances that it can contain, dictated by the tier.  For a non-dedicated tier, an Event Hubs namespace may have up to 10 Event Hub instances, each containing 1-32 partitions.  The [Event Hubs quotas and limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas#basic-vs-standard-vs-dedicated-tiers) documentation has the full details.

Comment: does anyone know why only 10? tool small. what to do if we need more? use another EventHubs namespace is not an option. Consolidate topics - hard to process different payloads

Comment: That, I do not know.  You'd need to ask the Event Hubs service team to understand the rationale.  The best way to engage them would be to open an Azure support request:  https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request